# How to display an Alert Controller when NSDate == to a time (for example 12:00 AM) in Swift?

Tags: swift

How to display an **Alert** or any other functions when the time equals 12:00 AM or any time...?

I tried this, but nothing shows when the time equals 12:44 AM:

```
let nowDate = NSDate() 
let nowFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
var nowString = NSString()

nowFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm a" 
nowString = nowFormatter.stringFromDate(nowDate)

if nowFormatter.dateFormat == "12:44 a" {  
       let UIAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)  
       let OKB = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
       UIAlert.addAction(OKB)
       self.presentViewController(UIAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a background timer to fire on or after the time you want to set:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer: NSTimer!

    func viewDidLoad() {
        let fireDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: 2016, month: 6, day: 17, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!
        self.timer = NSTimer(fireDate: fireDate, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.displayAlert), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(self.timer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    }

    func displayAlert() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Timer fired", message: "Hey, timer is fired", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't accepted my answer. Why should I help you again?

Comment: See the [Site FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Anyhow, translating it into ObjC is a new question.