# How to update/display data (for example image) based on the time range?

Tags: swift, swift3

For example I want the Image named "Something" to be displayed from 9:00 till 11:00. Then, Image will be changed, and a new Image "Something else" will be displayed from 11:00 till 13:00 and so on.

I found some related solutions : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701071/swift-displaying-the-time-or-date-based-on-timestamp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870076/how-to-display-an-alert-controller-when-nsdate-to-a-time-for-example-1200-a), but they have an old syntax and a bit different purpose.

Could You help me please.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Are you using actual `Date` objects?

Comment: @JonBrooks No, it is an every day repeated function, there is no need for an  exact date.

Comment: Please show what you have tried (code) and in which issue you are running.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found the solution, when You are using calendar date components and using the switch for hour and minutes.